# Suppress Formula Fields And Text Object In Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a formula field on crystal reports. I wants to check it whether it may consists

negative value or not if it has negative value than suppress it or hide it.

My formula field name is **"Bal"**  which consists formula is as below:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar mytot;
mytot:={@TotalSale}-{@TRPurchaseTotal}
```

How to suppress Formula field and TextObject?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the Bal formula in your report -> Format Field -> Common tab -> Suppress formula: `currentfieldvalue < 0`